# Spark and HADOOP_PATH

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

There are two distributions from spark webpage. One with hadoop and one without.

I am using python to do the spark coding, so i installed spark through pip. I suppose the distribution downloaded by pip should be the same as the build with hadoop available on the spark website, as both of them carry the same set of jars.

The puzzling issue appears when i tried to create a sparksession  `.master('local[*]')` with this config `.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.13.0')`.

If i use the spark build with hadoop, everything works perfectly. The jars downloaded, the spark session created ....

But when i am using the pip version, this error occurs `java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset` and i failed to create a spark session....

The issue can be resolved by setting the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable, i have tried and it works. I just cannot explain the difference in their behavior... When i am using the Spark with hadoop build, i just need to add to the `PATH` variable and no `HADOOP_PATH` required. But this is not true when i am using the pip version - i need to set the `HADOOP_PATH` for things to works

### **How can this magic happens?**

i am using window, and there are some binary files (winutils.exe/hadoop.dll) in the hadoop_path folder which don't exist in the spark with hadoop distribution.

I thought the difference between the *spark with hadoop* & *spark without hadoop* distribution was just some hadoop jar missing. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose the distribution downloaded by pip should be the same as the build with hadoop

It is not. As written on the PyPi page for PySpark, it does not come with Hadoop.

> > This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for **interacting with an existing cluster** (be it Spark standalone, **YARN**, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to set up your own standalone Spark cluster

Your issue mostly stems from Hudi relying on Hadoop libraries, rather than Spark itself.

> winutils.exe/hadoop.dll) in the hadoop_path folder which don't exist in the spark with hadoop distribution

Correct, because Hadoop is built and distributed only for Linux systems. Mac and Windows users need extra installation steps.

Comment: just want to confirm the difference between the spark with Hadoop and without Hadoop is only the hadoop jars? After searching on the internet, I feel like the *with HADOOP* version doesn't really contain the hadoop installation. It just contains some more jars

Comment: I believe that's correct. It's only the Java classpath, not scripts to set up Hadoop, that Spark really needs. The "without hadoop" and pyspark version assume `hadoop classpath` command is working already